# Linearity and nonlinearity of systems

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

My teacher of Control Systems did some exercises at the seminar and I don't get it why he said that this system is not linear:

- $x_1'= x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_2u_1$
- $x_2'= x_2 + 3u_2$;
- $y_1 = x_1$

Variables are $x_1$ and $x_2$ (both aren't squared)

> The system has the following properties:
>
> Not linear
>
> Order: $2$ ($x_1'$ and $x_2'$ state variables)
>
> Outputs: $1(y_1)$
>
> Inputs: $2(u_1,u_2)$

Comment: I added subscripts, please check that I didn't introduce errors.

Comment: inputs are u1 and u2

Comment: this was never mentioned, he gave this kind of system and at first glance he ask us to tell if is linear,order of the system, outputs and inputs, in his course he say that inputs can influence the dynamics of the system, so that is why they are often seen as actuators, and outputs as sensors, the system is continousm we usually apply Laplace to get the solution in time, so i am tempted to say that is unit steps

Comment: The term $3x_2 u_1$ is non-linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be products of the terms either, like $x_2 u_1$. Consider this simple example:

$$x'=x u$$

Let $u=1$, then the solution is $x(t) = x(0) e^t$. Now let $u=2$, then the solution is $x(t) = x(0) e^{2t} \neq 2 x(0) e^t$ which violates the linearity conditions.